# Can save django model to mysql database, but ORM is broken

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following model

```
class ExamTimeslot(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

and I test my project under python's interactive mode through

```
python manage.py shell
```

I can save a insance of my model through

```
>>> s = datetime.datetime(2014,4,4,12,30,0,0,django.utils.timezone.utc)
>>> ex = ExamTimeslot(course=c, start_time=s)
>>> ex.save()
```

And when I check my MySQL database, the data is saved

```
mysql> select * from sm_examtimeslot;
+----+-----------+---------------------+
| id | course_id | start_time          |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 | 2014-04-04 12:30:00 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I query from shell through, nothing is returned

```
>>> ExamTimeslot.objects.all()
[]
```

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: My guess your settings.py is actually pointing to a different database.  Print out your db settings right before your insert to see if that's the issue.

Comment: I don't think so, because my other models work just fine, but when dealing with models with DateTimeField I got this problem

Comment: Have you overridden default manager?

Comment: What is the `ExamTimeslot._meta.db_table`?

Comment: @KamilRykowski No I have not.

Comment: @AndreyNelubin It is 'sm_examtimeslot'

Comment: show `print ExamTimeslot.objects.all().query`

Comment: @AndreyNelubin SELECT `sm_examtimeslot`.`id`, `sm_examtimeslot`.`course_id`, `sm_examtimeslot`.`start_time` FROM `sm_examtimeslot`